# How to access WFS 2.0.0 using Geotools

Tags: wfs, java, geotools

I am trying to access a WFS using geotools. Access is working with version 1.0.0 and 1.1.0 without problems. Here my code:

```
// Conenction
String getCapabilities = WFSDataStoreFactory.createGetCapabilitiesRequest(new URL("http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs"), new Version("2.0.0")).toString();
Map connectionParameters = new HashMap();
connectionParameters.put(WFSDataStoreFactory.URL.key, getCapabilities);
WFSDataStoreFactory dsf = new WFSDataStoreFactory();
WFSDataStore dataStore = dsf.createDataStore(connectionParameters);
// Layer
SimpleFeatureSource source = dataStore.getFeatureSource("maps:ne_10m_lakes");
// Features
SimpleFeatureCollection fc = source.getFeatures();
SimpleFeatureIterator iterator = fc.features();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    SimpleFeature sf = iterator.next();
    // dostuff
}
```

Using version 2.0.0 results in:

> Can't find a response parser factory for
>   DESCRIBE_FEATURETYPE/'application/xml' Failed to execute request
>   http://demo.opengeo.org:80/geoserver/wfs?REQUEST=DescribeFeatureType&VERSION=2.0.0&SERVICE=WFS
>   Exception in thread "main"
>   org.geotools.factory.FactoryNotFoundException: Can't find a response
>   parser factory for DESCRIBE_FEATURETYPE/'application/xml'     at
>   org.geotools.data.wfs.internal.WFSExtensions.findResponseFactory(WFSExtensions.java:106)
>     at
>   org.geotools.data.wfs.internal.WFSRequest.createResponse(WFSRequest.java:205)
>     at
>   org.geotools.data.wfs.internal.WFSRequest.createResponse(WFSRequest.java:38)
>     at
>   org.geotools.data.ows.AbstractOpenWebService.internalIssueRequest(AbstractOpenWebService.java:445)
>     at
>   org.geotools.data.wfs.internal.WFSClient.internalIssueRequest(WFSClient.java:292)
>     at
>   org.geotools.data.wfs.internal.WFSClient.issueRequest(WFSClient.java:354)
>     at
>   org.geotools.data.wfs.WFSDataStore.getRemoteFeatureType(WFSDataStore.java:210)
>     at
>   org.geotools.data.wfs.WFSDataStore.getRemoteSimpleFeatureType(WFSDataStore.java:264)
>     at
>   org.geotools.data.wfs.WFSFeatureSource.buildFeatureType(WFSFeatureSource.java:348)
>     at
>   org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureSource.getAbsoluteSchema(ContentFeatureSource.java:356)
>     at
>   org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureSource.getSchema(ContentFeatureSource.java:325)
>     at
>   org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureCollection.(ContentFeatureCollection.java:80)
>     at
>   org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureSource.getFeatures(ContentFeatureSource.java:583)
>     at
>   org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureSource.getFeatures(ContentFeatureSource.java:114)
>     at TestWFS.main(TestWFS.java:79)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WFS-ng plugin only supports 1.0 & 1.1.0 as mentioned in the [documentation](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/data/wfs-ng.html).

Answer (score 2):

This particular WFS server is currently down at the moment (`503 Not Available`) so I can't test it.

But contrary to what the documentation (does not) says, GeoTools *does* provide support for WFS **2.0.0**: see the code available at https://github.com/geotools/geotools/tree/master/modules/unsupported/wfs-ng/src/main/java/org/geotools/data/wfs/internal/v2_0.